# How does one say "smokechaser" in German?

Tags: english-to-german

I would like to know if there is a word, in German, for smokechaser as defined below?

[smokechaser](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/smokechaser?r=66): a person who fights forest fires, esp. one with lightweight equipment.

Danke im voraus!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe "Waldbrandbekämpfer"?

"Waldbrand" is the German word meaning "forest fire". The Wikipedia page for [Waldbrand](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waldbrand) has more related terms.